# Function rules(), store() and update() in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to change the value of my fields `matriculation` and `number_motorbike` but visibly the values exist already. I have a problem of validation.

In my function **rules()** I have this: (no problem)

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'matriculation' => 'required|string|max:15|min:6|unique:motorbikes,matriculation',
            'number_motorbike' => 'required|string|max:6|min:6|unique:motorbikes,number_motorbike'
        ];
    }
```

In my function **store()** I have this: (no problem)

```
ublic function store(MotoRequest $request)
    {


       $exists = Motorbike::where('matriculation', $request->get('matriculation'))->where('number_motorbike', $request->get('number_motorbike'))->count();

       if (!$exists){
            Motorbike::create($request->all());
            return redirect()->route('motorbikes.index')
                ->with('success', 'new data created successfully');
        }

        else{
            return redirect()->route('motorbikes.index')
                ->with('error', 'duplicate');

        }   

    }
```

[image]

My problem is in my function update(), when I want for example change only the value of my field `matriculation` , I get an error message "The number motorbike has already been taken."

[image]

Here my function update() but I think the problem is in my function rules()?

```
public function edit($id)
    {
        $motorbikes = Motorbike::find($id);
        return view('admin.motorbikes.edit', compact('motorbikes'));
    }

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(MotoRequest $request, $id)
{

    $motorbikes = Motorbike::find($id);
    $motorbikes->matriculation = $request->get('matriculation');
    $motorbikes->number_motorbike = $request->get('number_motorbike');
    $motorbikes->save();
    return redirect()->route('motorbikes.index')
        ->with('success', 'Update!')->withInput();
}
```

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-unique - Forcing A Unique Rule To Ignore A Given ID ... should give you a place to start

Comment: @lagbox: Thank you, but where place the `ignore`,  I don't understand the doc `required|string|max:15|min:6|unique:motorbikes,matriculation',`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use forcing a unique rule to ignore an id: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#rule-unique

You need custom rules for update and store methods. Best way to implement is to validate request within the method. Therefore you should remove rules() method from MotoRequest class.

```
public function update(MotoRequest $request, $id)
{

    $motorbikes = Motorbike::find($id);

    $request->validate([
        'matriculation' => [
            'required','string','max:15','min:6',
            Rule::unique('motorbikes')->ignore($motorbikes) 

        ],
        'number_motorbike' => [
            'required','string','max:6','min:6',
            Rule::unique('motorbikes')->ignore($motorbikes) 
        ]
    ]);

    $motorbikes->matriculation = $request->get('matriculation');
    $motorbikes->number_motorbike = $request->get('number_motorbike');
    $motorbikes->save();
    return redirect()->route('motorbikes.index')
        ->with('success', 'Update!')->withInput();
}
```

Additionally, you do not need to check if record exists in database again in **store()** because it will already be validated.

```
public function store(MotoRequest $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'matriculation' => 'required|string|max:15|min:6|unique:motorbikes,matriculation',
        'number_motorbike' => 'required|string|max:6|min:6|unique:motorbikes,number_motorbike'
    ]);


    Motorbike::create($request->all());
    return redirect()->route('motorbikes.index')
        ->with('success', 'new data created successfully');

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, but I still have the same problem. As I understand it, you use the function "rules" 2 times? In the folder MotorbikeRequest.php and the MotorbikeController?

Comment: No, I don't use rules() function at all. I validate requests within the controller methods.

Comment: @ Anar Mammad: Thank you a lot, Anar It's OK... :-)

Answer (score 0):

I believe its your `rules` function that is the issue, when you are trying to update an item it is passing through the rules function and seeing that it already exists and passing the error message.

Take a look at the laravel validation docs 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-unique

Basically you will need a different validation rule for creating motorbikes to the one used for updating motorbikes. 
The update one will require you to ignore the current values

Comment: I have tried the regle "ignore" , but I think that I have a problem with the syntax ? `'matriculation' => 'required|string|max:15|min:6|unique:motorbikes->ignore($matriculation->id)' `